# How to assign multiple attributes to ActiveRecord::Relation array in single step?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

There is a function is rails to assign attributes to a Model `ActiveRecord` instance(single record) without saving(or updating).

For example:

```
$> post = Post.last #=> #<Post id: 53, title: 'Alpha', user_id: 39, state: 'published'>
$> post.assign_attributes(state: 'pending') #=> nil
$> post #=> #<Post id: 53, title: 'Alpha', user_id: 39, state: 'pending'>
```

but post is not saved in db.

Same I want to do with multiple records of `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

For example:

```
$> posts = Post.where(state: 'published')
#=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Post id: 50, title: 'Wonderful', user_id: 39, state: 'published'>, #<Post id: 53, title: 'Alpha', user_id: 39, state: 'published'>]>
$> posts.assign_attributes(state: 'pending') #=> nil
$> posts
#=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Post id: 50, title: 'Wonderful', user_id: 39, state: 'pending'>, #<Post id: 53, title: 'Alpha', user_id: 39, state: 'pending'>]>
```

Comment: There's no built-in function by now. You can just iterate over the elements of `posts` and invoke `assign_attributes` on them.

Comment: `posts.each { |post| post.assign_attributes(state: 'pending') }` can be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Post.update_all` this is special, because it runs an `UPDATE ALL` SQL statement in the database. Therefore there's no need to iterate over the collection in memory.

Updating all records in ruby memory, on the other hand, cannot do this; you do need to iterate over them:

```
posts.each { |post| post.assign_attributes(state: 'pending') }
```

---

However, this shouldn't be an issue. I can't think of any scenario where you'd want to update a collection of objects *in memory*, without also wanting to iterate over them at some point.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do mass assignment in rails like this

```
posts.each {|post| post.assign_attributes(state: 'pending')}
```

`each` perform operation and do not change nature for `posts`. So `posts` will be `ActiveRecord::Relation` object.